# Guardar y cargar txt de Entry, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

continuo practicando un poco, esta vez haciendo un pequeño codigo que utilice interfaz de usuario.
Basicamente es una tabla, donde tengo 3 columnas repartidas de la siguiente manera:
2 columnas con 27 filas de entry cada una y 1 tercera columna con 19 filas de entry cada una.

Yo cargo los datos que necesito, y luego de crear un boton "Guardar" los datos se guardan en un txt, pero traspuestos

```
def save(entries):
    with open(rutatxt,"w") as file:
        for entry_row in entries:
            row_data = [entry.get() for entry in entry_row]
            row_str = "|".join(row_data) + "|" #separador de columnas
            file.write(row_str + "\n")
```

hasta ahi funciona todo bien.
Ahora el problema es cuando llamo a la funcion load(), donde me carga en la columna 1, fila 1, el valor correspondiente, pero luego en columna 2, fila 2, me carga el valor que deberia ir en columna 1, fila 2.

```
def load(entries):
    with open(rutatxt, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

        # Obtener datos de filas
        rows_data = [line.strip().split("|") for line in lines]

        # Transponer filas y columnas
        transposed_data = list(zip(*rows_data))

        # Asegurar que haya suficientes columnas y filas
        for i in range(min(len(entries), len(transposed_data))):
            for j in range(min(len(entries[i]), len(transposed_data[i]))):
                entries[i][j].delete(0, END)
                entries[i][j].insert(0, transposed_data[i][j])
```

Alguien puede ver el error que hace que no funcione?
Gracias!

---

El codigo para crear el entry es asi:

```
for habitacion in columna_1:
    habitacion = Label(marco_habitaciones,
                       text=habitacion.title(),
                       font=("Arial",14),
                       bg="#cacab9",
                       fg="black",
                       padx = 1,
                       width=5,
                       bd=2,relief=RAISED)
    habitacion.grid(row=contador,column=1)
    contador += 1

contador = 0
for habitacion in columna_2:
    habitacion = Label(marco_habitaciones,
                       text=habitacion.title(),
                       font=("Arial",14),
                       bg="#cacab9",
                       fg="black",
                       padx = 1,
                       width=5,
                       bd=2,relief=RAISED)
    habitacion.grid(row=contador,column=3)
    contador += 1

contador = 0
for habitacion in columna_3:
    habitacion = Label(marco_habitaciones,
                       text=habitacion.title(),
                       font=("Arial",14),
                       bg="#cacab9",
                       fg="black",
                       padx = 1,
                       width=5,
                       bd=2,relief=RAISED)
    habitacion.grid(row=contador,column=5)
    contador += 1

contador = 0
columna_1_entries = []
for i in columna_1:
    estado1 = Entry(marco_habitaciones, font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="white", fg="Blue",justify=CENTER)
    estado1.grid(row=contador,column= 2)
    contador += 1
    columna_1_entries.append(estado1)
contador = 0

columna_2_entries = []
for i in columna_2:
    estado2 = Entry(marco_habitaciones, font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="white", fg="Blue", justify=CENTER)
    estado2.grid(row=contador,column= 4)
    contador += 1
    columna_2_entries.append(estado2)
contador = 0

columna_3_entries = []
for i in columna_3:
    estado3 = Entry(marco_habitaciones, font=("Arial", 12, "bold"), bg="white", fg="Blue",justify=CENTER)
    estado3.grid(row=contador,column= 6)
    contador += 1
    columna_3_entries.append(estado3)
```

columna_1 y columna_2 , es una lista que tienen 27 elementos y columna_3 una lista que tiene 19 elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría saber de qué forma estás creando tu matriz entries, es decir, si las celdas Entry las creas como fila o como columna. Si las estás creando como fila, al momento de leer la matriz dentro de la función save y luego guardarla, esta se te escribiría con la misma distribución que tienes en tu interfaz, y no habría necesidad de trasponer los datos. Si lo haces así, creo que sería mucho más sencillo el leer y llenar nuevamente los valores en las celdas Entry a partir de una matriz alojada en un txt.

De acuerdo con la información que suministras, creo poder intuir que la matriz entries es más o menos así: `entries = [columna_1_entries, columna_2_entries, columna_3_entries]`

Con lo anterior, y viendo el formato en que lees y guardas tus entries, dentro de tu txt se estarían guardando tus renglones como columnas. Esto es, si se echara un vistazo a tu txt, se vería más o menos de la siguiente manera:

```
r1c1|r2c1|r3c1|...|r27c1|
r1c2|r2c2|r3c2|...|r27c2|
r1c3|r2c3|...|r19c3|
```

*r y c: reglón y columna, respectivamente.

Ahora bien, revisando la función load, cuando usas el método readlines, estarías creando una lista que se vería más o menos así:

```
lines = ["r1c1|r2c1|r3c1|...|r27c1|", "r1c2|r2c2|r3c2|...|r27c2|", "r1c3|r2c3|...|r19c3|"]
```

Suponiendo que la información alojada en el txt es suficiente para rellenar todas las entradas alojadas en la matriz entries, solo basta con recorrer la matriz de la siguiente manera:

```
for entradas, valores in zip(entries, lines):
    rows_data = valores.split("|")
    for i in range(len(entradas)):
        entradas[i].delete(0, END)
        entradas[i].insert(0, rows_data[i])
```

Si es correcto el análisis, con esto sería suficiente para que tu código haga lo que realmente quieres que realice.
Espero haber sido de ayuda.